# How to get process name and memory usage from a remote workstation(s)

Tags: wmic

I have to monitor process performance on remote workstationsj within my organization. I have tried Component Services and Computer Management on a remote workstaiton but processes are not listed there only services.

Comment: You might want to show what you tried, and what, if any, error messages you are getting.

Comment: I tried this which worked: (with my admin rights) tasklist.exe /S SYSTEM /U USERNAME /P PASSWORD, however i now want to see if there is a better way of doing this to get memory usage on multiple workstations.  Example I am testing about 40 workstations, before I deploy an agent I want to make sure the memory usage is low